# How to write a list with one element as just an element in CSV and not a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am performing some manipulations to a dataframe and when I print the frame there are columns with one value in a list. My code is follows:

```
import pandas as pd

something = [[1, "p", "dsd"], [3, "t", "dsd"], [6, "u", "sds"], [1, "p", "dsd"], [4, "l", "dsds"], [1, "t", "dsd"], [3, "t", "dsds"], [6, "c", "cxxc"], [1, "p", "dsd"], [4, "l", "vdv"]]
test = pd.DataFrame(something)
test = test.drop_duplicates()
test.columns = ['id', 'state', 'level']
test = test.sort_values(by=['id'], ascending=True)
test_unique = test["id"].unique()

df_aslist = test.groupby(['id']).aggregate(lambda x: list(x)).reset_index()
#making it a set to remove duplicates
df_aslist['level'] = df_aslist['level'].apply(lambda x: list(set(x)))
print(df_aslist)
df_aslist.to_csv("data.csv", mode="w", header=False)
```

The output is

```
   id   state        level
0   1  [p, t]        [dsd]
1   3  [t, t]  [dsd, dsds]
2   4  [l, l]  [dsds, vdv]
3   6  [u, c]  [sds, cxxc]
```

It is written as the same to csv file. But `[dsd]` is just one value. I want to store it as a regular string rather than a list. How can this be accomplished?

Comment: I think this should do the trick, `test.groupby(['id'], as_index=False).agg({"id": "first", "state": list, "level": lambda x: set(x) if len(set(x)) > 1 else list(set(x))[0]})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get your single element list to be just a value

```
df_aslist = test.groupby(['id']).aggregate(lambda x: list(x)).reset_index()
df_aslist['level'] = df_aslist['level'].apply(lambda x: list(set(x))[0] if len(list(set(x))) == 1 else list(set(x)) )

   id   state        level
0   1  [p, t]          dsd
1   3  [t, t]  [dsd, dsds]
2   4  [l, l]  [vdv, dsds]
3   6  [u, c]  [cxxc, sds]
```